# What is the difference between the ways to read an Image file in Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, color-channel

There are various ways of reading an image file in java such as `BufferedImage` and `ImageIcon` to name a few. I want to know what is the difference between these cases? Are they context dependent that in a particular case only one of them can be used?

What would be the best way of reading a image selected by `JFileChooser` by the user and separating the color channels of an image?

Comment: *"reading Image file in java such as BufferedImage"*  The `BufferedImage` API offers no method for reading images.  DYM `javax.imageio.ImageIO`, and `java.awt.Toolkit`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good way is to use the different ImageIO.read methods, which return BufferedImage objects.

Image is an abstract class, so I think the real question is which subclass is more efficient for your program. Use VolatileImage if you need hardware acceleration. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178907/hardware-accelerate-bitmap-drawing-in-java/4179617#4179617).

Comment: Agreed, ImageIO is the way to go (when not using JavaFX at least).

Comment: @Gimby: How would you do it when using JavaFX?

Answer (score 3):

`ImageIcon` (and `Toolkit#createImage`/`Toolkit#getImage`) use a background loading process.  That is, after you call these methods, they will return immediately, having created a background thread to actually load the image data.

These were/are used when loading large images across slow connections, like ye old 28k modems (ah, how I remember the days).  This means that your application can continue running while the images are been downloaded.

You'll find in the `Graphics` class the `drawImage` methods accept an `ImageObserver` interface and that `java.awt.Component` implements this interface, this allows components the ability to automatically update themselves once the image has actually finished loading.

`ImageIO` on the other hand will not return until the image is fully loaded. It also makes it easier to introduce new readers/writers, making the API far more flexible then the original API.  `ImageIO` also supports a wider range of images out of the box.

`BufferedImage` is also a far more flexible image class, especially when it comes to apply effects to the image.

Now, I, personally, prefer `ImageIO`. If I know I'm loading large images or images over a potentially slow connection, I will create my own background thread to load them. While a little more complicated, the trade offs greatly out weight the small amount of extra work -IMHO

> What would be the best way of reading a image selected by JFileChooser by the user and separating the color channels of an image?

`ImageIO` without a doubt.  In order to do any serious manipulation of an image loaded using something `ImageIcon`, you'd have to convert that image to a `BufferedImage` anyway