# What is difference between these two kinds of image loading code?

Tags: java, image

These two kinds of code below are used for loading an Image file:

**A)**

```
File sourceimage = new File("filename");
Image image = ImageIO.read(sourceimage);
```

**B)**

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDeafaultToolkit();
img=tk.getImage("filename");
```

What's the real difference between these two codes ?

Comment: different means to achieve the same goal I suppose

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136475/what-is-the-difference-between-the-ways-to-read-an-image-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

[`ImageIO.read(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) takes a `File` and is newer than [`Toolkit.getImage(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a `filename` (and has been part of the language longer). Also, the first one provides additional functionality (that is, the `ImageIO.read(File)` javadoc says in part)

> The current cache settings from `getUseCache` and `getCacheDirectory` will be used to control caching in the `ImageInputStream` that is created.
>
> Note that there is no read method that takes a filename as a String; use this method instead after creating a `File` from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the primary difference between the two is that `Toolkit.getImage` returns a `java.awt.Image`, while `ImageIO.read` return a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` (which is a subclass of `java.awt.Image`).

An `Image` object is a fairly abstract image representation that you can't do very much with apart from pass to the various `Graphics.drawImage` methods, while a `BufferedImage` contains the full image data, so that you can inspect individual pixels, modify them and also, for instance, save the image (to a new file and/or a new file format).